# Solve the Differential Equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=2+\sqrt{y-2x+3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I re-arranged the equation to appear as such: $$1+2x=y+4\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}-\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$$ None of the techniques I have learned so far help me to proceed here; particularly, the $\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$ term makes it difficult to assess. I know that it is first-order non-linear, however. Is there a classification for this equation, or a formula that I may use to proceed? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put $z:=y-2x$. Then the equation looks like

$$z'=\sqrt{z+3}$$

Separate variables.

$$\frac{dz}{\sqrt{z+3}}=dx$$

$$ 2\sqrt{z+3}=x+C$$

Hence $$2\sqrt{y-2x+3}=x+C$$